# Evaluating integral with difference argument inside sumation

Tags: integration, summation

I am working with an expression that looks like this ($n,m$ are integers, whereas $a,b$ are constants, real numbers):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n,m}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy f_{n}(x-na)g_{m}(y+mb)
\end{eqnarray}
My question is if the following change of variables $w=x-na$ and $z=y+mb$ is allowed in order to write the expression as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n,m}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dw\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dz f_{n}(w)g_{m}(z)
\end{eqnarray}
Since the limits of integration are not changed, this should in principle not change the value of the sum; however, the change of variables contains explicitly the integers $n,m$ and this is my doubt, I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is allowable.

For each fixed $n, m$, the change does not affect the value of the integral. And since the values being summed are the same before and after the change, the sum itself will not change.